# How does Kestrel know the virtual directory it is running under in IIS?

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, iis, kestrel

We are trying to migrate our aspnetcore web apps from our own Windows/IIS server to AWS using ECS and API Gateway.  We have everything working but ran into an unexpected issue with redirects inside our web applications.  Our web site is setup like this in IIS:

```
/ => the root website is pointing to another web app
/app1 => app1 is setup as a virtual directory pointing to an empty folder
/app1/v1 => v1 is setup as an application pointing to an aspnetcore app
/app2/v1 => again v1 is setup as an application pointing to a different aspnetcore app
```

I have a very simple out of the box aspnetcore application that is setup as a virtual directory under /app1/v1.  The routes in the aspnetcore application are:

```
/Web
/Web/Login
/Web/Home
```

When a user first visits the site (http://localhost/app1/v1/Web) they are redirected to the login page using:

```
Redirect("~/Web/Login")
```

When the application is run by IIS that results in the browser being redirected to:

```
http://localhost/app1/v1/Web/Login
```

However when I use a reverse proxy, like AWS API Gateway, that has been setup with the same virtual path it redirects to:

```
http://localhost/Web/Login
```

I'm guessing that there must be a configuration value that I need to pass into Kestrel during startup or as a request header to tell it to add "/app1/v1/" to any ~/ redirects that it performs?.  Does anyone know how IIS is telling Kestrel the full path and how I can replicate that behavior?

Comment: Very likely an environmental variable.

Answer (score 1):

> Whenever asp.net runtime redirects,it will always use the base path
>   from the root .In your case the problem is ~ passed.This is telling
>   the browser to redirect from the base path which is /.

You can do remove the ~ and try giving Redirect("Web/Login").But I have seen asp.net runtime always add Reidrect Response wiht Location Header as "~/Web/Login".

So if removing the ~ does not work,you can try with

`Response.RedirectToAbsoluteUrl("Web/Login");`

**Edit:**

*To explain the scenario why this may be happening when you do reverse proxy*

Normally you setup a reverse proxy like this

```
www.example.com => servername:8080
```

When the proxy forwards the request,server(asp.net) does not know anything about the www.example.com ,to that asp.net runtime the request hostname is servername.

Now when you do redirect, what the asp.net runtime sends is a [302 response](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_302)

This will look like this

```
Client request:

GET /app1/v1/Webl HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost
Server response:

HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Location: ~/Web/Login
```

Please check out this with a fiddler if you would like to confirm

Now when behind a reverse proxy where you may have setup like this

```
www.example.com/myapp => servername:8080 

 www.example.com/anotherapp => servername2:8080
```

You can double check how is the reverse proxy setup.Now imagine the same 302 response but your application does not know what is the relative path (www.example.com/myapp) .This causes problem with the what Location header is send in the response(if it has ~,this causes problems with relative paths in the original URL .

Hope this helps!.

Comment: The code works fine when IIS is managing the Kestrel worker process so I don't think this is an issue with the way we redirecting.  The problem only pops up when we manually run Kestrel and have a reverse proxy route connections into it which is why I believe there is a configuration value we can use to pass in the base path.

Comment: yes the relative path am suspecting because of way reverse proxy usually  setup.Added more detail,please double check